# Did Microsoft remove the option to send a file with Lync 2013?

Tags: microsoft-office, file-transfer, lync, lync-2013

Until recently we used the Lync option for sending files to transfer big files between our work team members. Today I was looking for this option to send a 30MB file to my colleague, but could not find it. Asking around, I heard that the option was disabled by MS, but I cannot find an evidence for that online.

Was this option really removed? Why?

Comment: If it was there in the same version then it wasn't removed by Microsoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further inquiry reveals that the option was blocked by the IT Dept. for some security measures...